# Converting HTML date to Oracle date

Tags: php, oracle, date

I have an html input type date that i want to insert into oracle date. How do I make the conversion into the oracle date? so far I have this,

```
<label><span>DUE DATE</span>
    <input id="duedate" type="date" name="duedate" size="10" maxlength="10" value="" />         
</label>

<label><span>&nbsp;</span>
    <input class ="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
</label>
</form>
```

```
 <?php
  // If the submit button has been pressed...

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {    
    $s = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO TIMESPAN
         (HEAD_MARK, INIT_DATE, DUE_DATE, SUBCONT_ID, REMARKS)
          VALUES (:hMark, SYSDATE, :dueDate, :subcontId, :remarks)");

    oci_bind_by_name($s, ":hMark", $_POST['headmark']);
    oci_bind_by_name($s, ":dueDate", $_POST['duedate']);
    oci_bind_by_name($s, ":subcontId", $_POST['subcontid']);
    oci_bind_by_name($s, ":remarks", $_POST['remarks']);

    $result = oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);

    if ($result)
        {
            oci_commit($conn); // COMMIT TRANSACTION
            echo 'INSERT TO DB COMPLETED';
        } else {
            oci_rollback($conn); // ROLLBACK INSERTION
            $m = oci_error($s);
            echo "ERROR OCCURED".$m;
        }
    oci_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dd-MMM-yy` format then something like this should work:

```
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":dueDate", strtoupper(date('d-M-y', strtotime($_POST['duedate']))));
```

Comment: Caught an error :(

Fatal error: Call to undefined function strtotupper() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\subcont_assignment.php on line 91

Comment: Sorry, typo. `strtoupper()`

Answer (score 0):

To put a "string" date into a "date" variable type in Oracle you need to use the TO_DATE() pl/sql command: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

```
TO_DATE($_POST['duedate'], 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```